# NSSplitView: how to not resize with the window but only in "manual" way?

Tags: objective-c, nssplitview

I' ve a simple vertical `NSSplitView` and I wan't that keeps his size when I resize the windows but I want to allow the resize of the `NSSplitView` manually when dragging the vertical bar that divides the two views.

EDIT. This is the code I' ve added and for some reason all goes wrong: the left pane (sourceView) keeps the same size while resizing the window but the right pane that has a correct auto layout constraints (works well without implementing the method below). The NSSrollView is the left pane that I wan' t to remain in the same position and the other view may resize with the window.

```
- (BOOL)splitView:(NSSplitView *)splitView shouldAdjustSizeOfSubview:(NSView *)subview
{
    if ([subview class] == [NSScrollView class])
        return NO;

    return YES;

}
```

Anyone know a fast solution to do that? Thanks!

Comment: did you tried implementing the NSSplitView Delegate methods ?

Comment: Yes, see the comments in the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 4.6, The left custom view of the vertical split view **is not NSScrollView**.

```
@synthesize leftView;

- (BOOL)splitView:(NSSplitView *)splitView shouldAdjustSizeOfSubview:(NSView *)subview {
    if (subview == leftView) return NO;
    else return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the split view item's behavior as Sidebar

Comment: Best answer so far

Comment: Note: this property is only available via storyboards or when creating `NSSplitViewItem` [from code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssplitviewitem/1388920-sidebarwithviewcontroller?language=objc) because you can't add them in a XIB file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `NSSplitViewDelegate`.   In particular, you need to make sure that you return `NO` for `-splitView:shouldAdjustSizeOfSubview:`, which will prevent the auto-resize.

Since you have at least 2 subviews in each of the splitViews, you'll need to determine which one you don't want to move, so return `NO` just for it and `YES` for the view you want to change.    So, for example, if you have a source list, and you want it to remain unchanged except in a manual manipulation, return `NO` for the source list and `YES` for the other side.

Comment: This is exactly what I did but for some reason it doesn't work: the left pane remain the same size and this is ok but for some reason the other pane have a strange behavior: Sometimes its resizing is correct in relation with the autolayout constraints that I've set before but if I resize it again something goes wrong and the constraints are not met.

Comment: Can you amend your question to describe your auto layout constraints?   That's important to fully answering your question.

Comment: I try to do that but is not so easy because I have a complex view hierarchy. The strange thing is also that my right pane resizes itself correctly when the size of the window is changed but when I implement the method all goes wrong. For now I post the implementation of `- (BOOL)splitView:(NSSplitView *)splitView shouldAdjustSizeOfSubview:(NSView *)subview
` method and later today I try to post the all layout code